# hyperlink inserted with pandas need edit before working libreoffice

Tags: pandas, libreoffice

hyperlink inserted with pandas need edit before working libreoffice:

(using .to_excel in pandas)

hyperlink are ok, but showing 0,
if I add a space, for example, then press Enter, the link will come "alive" and I will be able to click on the hyperlink as normal.

I searched google for any hyperlink issues in libreoffice, and I could not find any that relevant as permission for hyperlink is allowed in my libreoffice.

Comment: This question is not clear, nor is there any indication of research effort.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: can you give code example?